# firebase_core trying to use bintray

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting an error with firebase packages, in particular I think firebase_core,

From what I can tell it's trying to get something from bintray, which is now shut down so it makes sense that it doesn't work. I'm using the latest version of `firebase_core: ^1.10.5` and `flutter 2.8.0` and dart `2.15.0`

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-core:[1.41.0].
     Required by:
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore > com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0 > io.grpc:grpc-android:1.41.0
         project :app > project :cloud_firestore > com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.0 > io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.41.0
      > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
```

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: @bawsi no I haven't yet

Answer (score 1):

I had to upgrade my whole project from older flutter version (1.22) to the latest one. Took a bit of work to update all the packages and implement all their changes, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

What got it working for me was upgrading to the latest version of flutter and using these package versions

```
  http: 0.12.2
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
```